# Label inside border not visible in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I'm migrating our Xamarin Forms App to MAUI and I'm trying to replace the frames with border. However, I encounter an issue with border because the label inside it is not showing, any idea what's the problem with my code?

Here's a snapshot of my xaml code side-by-side with Frame just for comparison.

```xml
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border
        Stroke="Transparent"
        BackgroundColor="Aqua"
        Padding="0"
        WidthRequest="60"
        HeightRequest="60">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="30" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Label
            TextColor="Black"
            Text="7"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Frame
        BorderColor="Transparent"
        CornerRadius="30"
        WidthRequest="60"
        HeightRequest="60"
        Padding="0"
        BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Label
            TextColor="Black"
            Text="7"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

    </Frame>
  </StackLayout>
```

and here's its output in the simulator:

[image]

I'm expecting that the label inside the border will be displayed.

Comment: Is your label even visible inside the border control?

Comment: They fixed some of the border bugs in IOS in NET 8. (Waiting for the clipping myself.) Not sure if this is related or not. Just saying that it is not working well on IOS anyway...

Comment: @FreakyAli, it is not.. The aqua colored circle is using Border while the yellow one is using Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this question on iOS, and here is a workaround,

Wrap the label in a StackLayout or Grid with `VerticalOptions="Center"`

```
<Border
    ...

     <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label 
        TextColor="Black"
        Text="7"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
     </StackLayout>

</Border>
```

It works for both iOS and Android. You could also raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes this will work as work-around, but I think its a bug that MAUI devs should fix. The Label alone must be displayed just like in Frame.

Comment: I cannot agree more. So you could raise an issue on GitHub and let them know and follow up that thread.